# RMI latency on Windows

Tags: java, windows, rmi, latency

I'm implementing a client-server game in java. As to the connection layer, you can choose to use RMI or Sockets. I'm experiencing huge lantency (roughly 20-30 seconds) using RMI with a Win10 client and a Win11 server on a private network (created using ZeroTier) run on two different machines with a physical distance of 200km. I thought the latency was due to the distance of the two machines, but if I go for the Socket connection layer, the latency is orders of magnitude smaller. After checking in the java RMI FAQ, I noticed that at C.6 they say that latency in Win Platforms might be a consequence of DNS lookup timeouts. They say that, in order to fix it, you have to add to the "hosts" file a hostname/address mapping. Now, my question is: what entry should I add exactly to the hosts file? I know that the address is determined by what ZeroTier assigns me, but what should the hostname be?

Comment: Just use sockets. Almost nothing uses RMI these days. Unless you need to learn about RPC concepts.

Comment: @aled Yes, ok I see your point. This is a school project and they want us to use RMI, so I have to use it.

Comment: RMI latency is usually DNS latency. Physical distance only adds milliseconds. You need to look up the `/etc/hosts` file format. Not really on-topic here.

Comment: @user207421 ok I did take a look at it. The thing is that I don't have any idea what I should set the hostname to.

Comment: Err, to its IP address?

Comment: that's the ip address of the host, but what about the hostname?